# How to get multiple images from Flask request object at once in case of Content-Type:multipart/form-data?

Tags: python, numpy, flask

I'm supposed to get multiple image files from the requests, but I can't find a way to split a byte string `request.files[key].read()` properly to make `np.ndarrays` out of them.

Comment: first check what you get with `request.files` and `request.files[key]`

Comment: This question needs to be explained much better. "I can't find a way" is not an error anyone can ever solve. Add more details, reproducible code and the error you encountered.

Comment: `files[key]` gives only one object with `name=key` and `.read()` gives data only for this single flie. You need `files.getlist(key)` to get list with all files which have `name=key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files[key]` gives only one object which has `name=key` in `HTML`, and `.read()` gives data only for this single file. So there is no need to split it.

If you have many files with `name=key` then you need `files.getlist(key)` to get list with all files and next use `for`-loop to read every file separatelly.

```
for item in request.files.getlist('image'):
    data = item.read()
    print('len:', len(data))
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #print('args :', request.args)
        #print('form :', request.form)
        #print('json :', request.json)
        #print('files:', request.files)
        print(request.files['image'])
        print(request.files.getlist('image'))
        
        for item in request.files.getlist('image'):
            data = item.read()
            print('len:', len(data))
        
    return render_template_string('''
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Single image: <input type="file" name="image"/></br>
Multiple images: <input type="file" name="image" multiple/></br>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="send">Send</button>
</form>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```